# Auto_complete_for question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I've recently installed this plugin, and I meant to create a Tag field with it, like StackOverFlow does.

When I put the following syntax on my AnnouncementsController(I want to tag announcements) it works great:

```
  auto_complete_for :announcement, :title
  protect_from_forgery :only => [:create, :delete, :update]
```

Also, I had to add the routes syntax as well to make it work:

```
map.resources :announcements, :collection => {:auto_complete_for_announcement_title => :get }
```

Now, when I try to accomplish the same with the tags, at the time I create a new announcement, I simply replace the word "announcement" for "tag" and "title" for "name", and it won't work. Tag makes reference for my Tags table at the database.

The error says the following:

```
<h1>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

    in AnnouncementsController#show    </h1> 
<pre>Couldn't find Announcement with ID=auto_complete_for_tag_name</pre>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

In your view you probably want to change:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :announcement, :title %>
```

to:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :tag, :name %>
```

to make it work, take another look at the error it's giving, it's still calling announcement.

--- edit:

from [autocomplete source](http://github.com/rails/auto_complete/blob/master/lib/auto_complete_macros_helper.rb):

```
 def text_field_with_auto_complete(object, method, tag_options = {}, completion_options = {})
```

Comment: I don't understand something:

what do the parameters for text_field_with_auto_complete refer to? And the same question for the auto_complete_for method.

Because I'm trying to make it work for Tags, from my Announcements view.

Comment: The one that works is the following:
Tags2: <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :announcement, :title, {}, {:method =>
:get} %>

And the one that does not work is the following:

Tags: <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :tag, :name, {}, {:method =>
:get} %>

Comment: Check http calls with something like Firebug's Net tab.
It seems that the text field observed by the js function is calling the wrong url: '/announcements/auto_complete_for_tag_name?params...'
Have you defined: map.resources :tags, :collection => {:auto_complete_for_tag_name => :get } in your routes?

Comment: Thanks. I guess this website has the clue for this. I have to read it carefully and test it.

What do you think?

URL : http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/1/30/sample-app-for-auto-complete-on-a-complex-form

Comment: Yes, I do have that in my routes file. Should I use a fields_to :tag in my announcements' view and within there write f.text_field_with_auto_complete :tag, :name...?

Comment: I realized that when I type something at that text_field, it goes to the Show method of the Announcements Controller, and the id is auto_complete_for_tag_name, so that's why I'm getting that error. The question is why it goes to that method if i'm at the New view, not showing anything!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got the answer to my problem.

I was missing the following at routes.rb:

```
  map.auto_complete '/:controller/:action',
     :requirements => { :action => /auto_complete_for_\S+/ },
     :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

My new question now it works is the following:

What if I wanted to multi-tag an announcements, for example: "Ruby, C#". Should I change the plugin's logic or is there a functionality to make this work? Cause right now, it will check for the text_field text, not discriminating a new word after a comma or any kind of separator.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: I could do this with "token => ','" after the "method" parameter in the view.